# Looking for specific Java web chart libraries

Tags: java, charts

At work we're looking for charting libraries satisfying very specific requirements. So far failing to find one. Maybe somebody here can help ?

- For a web application
- Java-based => JPA/RDBMS backend
- Generates server-side 2D charts as bitmap images => huge data sets
- Preferably streams through the data for rendering => huge volumes of data
- Uses WebGL for 3D charts
- Supports tables of any size => large number of columns and rows
- Extensible for custom chart types

I know there are many incredibly cool libraries out there. But none so far performs well when rendering huge volumes of data. Hence the requirement to render server-side images and send those images to the browser instead. Otherwise the browser chokes on the amount of data- and drawing instructions.

For 3D charts I could only find libraries doing a 2D projection. We'd like to use WebGL instead.

For tables we need something adding/removing columns/rows while the user scrolls through through the table. Because of the potentially huge number of columns and rows we can't keep it all in the DOM tree.

Some charts we need are pretty specific to the domain. That is, definitely not available out of the box. So we'll need an API to add our own.

Comment: Is this Jan Goyvaerts of EditPad and PowerGREP fame?

Comment: Nope. Neither am I the author of the Regex Cookbook. :-)

Comment: Or the football player for that matter. :-)

Comment: You may not be royalty, but we will try to treat you like a king.